# How to obtain multiple substring from a long text using a string as the starting value

Tags: python

Overall I have one string and I am trying to create substrings based on a given word.So let's say the given word is apple and the text is about different kind of fruits.

Text:
"Fruits are tasty. Apples can be red. Bananas are yellow. Apples can also be yellow."

How would I go about getting the characters after the word "apple" in the string? I only want a certain number of characters to be returned. For example if the character limit is 10: then I would get "apples can be re" and "apples can also ".

I tried turning the text into a list and iterating through it however, this process is too long. The index function also only returns the first instance of a given element. So I am not able to use the index to create a substring.

Comment: Use a regular expression: `Apples.{10}`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The regex library "re" works well for this and you can use re.finditer() to iterate over any matching groups found indicated by the pattern:

```
import re
str="Fruits are tasty. Apples can be red. Bananas are yellow. Apples can also be yellow."
pattern="apple"
amt=10

for match in re.finditer(pattern,str,re.IGNORECASE):
    span=match.end()+amt
    print(str[match.end():span])
```

Output:

- s can be r
- s can also

If you examine the match object created (<re.Match object; span=(18, 23), match='Apple'>) you can see the **span**, which indicates the start and end of the match. So match.end() plus however many characters you want to capture following the match should give you the text you want.